# actualizar a la ultima versión de firebase-tools

Tags: firebase, npm

Cuando ejecuto `firebase --version` en la terminal obtengo lo siguiente:

> 12.0.0

Al tratar de ejecutar el comando:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools to update
```

Me salen los siguientes errores:

> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.2.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.

¿Cómo lo puedo resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

Tú no puedes hacer nada, si son dependencias de firebase-tools, entonces Firebase terminará actualizando lo que haga falta con el tiempo.
Igualmente te recomiendo [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) que te ayuda a actualizar las librerías que sí se puedan actualizar en tus proyectos o globales.